# MongoDB replicate / master slave without remove transaction

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have Meteor and Mongodb project, and I consisted Mongodb as two replica set.

What I want to do is to make a secondary db as a backup system.
That means, I want to keep my all secondary data, even if the primary db was removed by a user.

The secondary replica set's data was removed when primary's data removed and I couldn't find any method to prevent this,
and I think Master / Slave would be same with the replica.

Is there any solution or application to do this?

Thanks in advance-

Comment: I think I had some mis-concept as the below said, but I'll keep this questions for someone who have the same questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Misconceptions

First of all: the Master/Slave replication is considered deprecated and will be removed in future versions. You shouldn't use it any more. It has no advantages over running a replica set with two data bearing nodes and an arbiter (except for the fact that it doesn't need an arbiter, which is cheap in memory, disk and CPU usage).

Second: a replication of any kind isn't a replacement for a backup, it enhances the availability of the data. Even more so with a replica set, since failover and tailback is automatic.

Third: to prevent databases from being dropped, you might want to use [authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/)(to identify users) and [authorization](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authorization/) to limit what each individual user can do.

#### What you *might* want to do instead

That being said, you might want to use a [delayed replica set member](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/), which might give you some time to react after a fatal command was issued, at the cost of data being outdated a bit. But still this has more to do with data availability than with data backup.

#### Taking backups

I haven't used MMS until now (the amount of data I had to deal with simply was way to big and MMS wasn't cost efficient for my customers). But I have made good experience with taking [LVM snapshots](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html) of [XFS filesystems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS)(which is one of [the recommended filesystems for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#kernel-and-file-systems)) for backups: it's easy, fast, cheap and easy to implement.

Comment: Yeah I might have some mis-conception. I think I should find another backup system instead making secondary to be backup one. Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Secondary replica is supposed to keep the same data as the primary. If you need backup your data, you may consider to use MongoDb MMS to schedule backup jobs.

Comment: You can consult the docs on [backup methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/) for more information.